# docker-registry - PUT request from python responds with 400, but Curl works fine

Tags: python, python-requests, docker-registry

i'm trying to `GET` a manifest v2 from my private registry and `PUT` it back under different tag. I am doing it in utility written in Python (`requests` lib)

If i save manifest of required image into JSON file and then do a `curl` command:

```sh
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:5000/v2/<repository>/manifests/latest' -H 'content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' -d @manifest.json
```

- it works and responding with 2xx. But if i try to do it in Python:

```py
manifest = requests.get(url='http://localhost:5000/v2/%s/manifests/%s' % (img, tag), 
                        headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'})
put_latest = requests.put(url='http://localhost:5000/v2/%s/manifests/latest' % image, 
                          headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'}, 
                          data=manifest.text)
```

- it just responding with `400 Bad Request` and `{'errors': [{'code': 'MANIFEST_INVALID', 'message': 'manifest invalid', 'detail': {}}]}`, and in `docker-registry` log it says that `err.detail="missing signature key"`.

What am in doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was sending wrong header key. I've should use `Content-Type` instead of `Accept`, which is used for `GET`, i suppose.

```py
manifest = requests.get(url='http://localhost:5000/v2/%s/manifests/%s' % (img, tag), 
                        headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'})
put_latest = requests.put(url='http://localhost:5000/v2/%s/manifests/latest' % image, 
                          headers={'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'}, 
                          data=manifest.text)
```